# what address is when add'*'before structure name in C

Tags: c, struct, implicit-conversion, sizeof, dereference

```
typedef struct PeoInfo
{
    char name[20];
    int age; 
    char sex[5]; 
    char tele[12]; 
    char addr[30];
}
struct PeoInfo c[10] = {0};
printf("p=%x\n", *c);
printf("p=%x\n", c[0]);
```

In this situation, `sizeof(c)` and `sizeof(*c)` have different results.
In my point of view, `c` is the entry of the array. But what is the `*c`?  The result of `sizeof(*c)` is the size of `PeoInfo`. When using `printf` to print the address of `*c` and `c[0]`, the result is also different.
I am really confused about it.

Comment: `c[i]` means `*(c+i)`, and conversely, `*c` means `c[0]`. You're getting the size of an array element.

Comment: `sizeof c` is the size of the whole array.

Comment: `sizeof(*c)` will give you the size of `struct PeoInfo`.

Comment: "*when i using printf to print the address of *c and c[0],the result also different*" -- this claim needs to be supported by code.  Since `*c` and `c[0]` are 100% equivalent for any valid pointer `c`, I am inclined to think that you are mistaken, but without code I can't tell you what specific mistake you made.

Comment: Please show the code in an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Answer (score 0):

In this expression `*c` the array designator c is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `struct PeoInfo *` and applying the dereference operator yields an object of the type `struct PeoInfo`.

So the expression `sizeof( *c )` where the expression `*c` is not evaluated and only its type is determinated yields the size of an object of the type `struct PeoInfo`.

As the subscript operator c[0] is calculated like *( c + 0 ) that is the same as *c then these printf statements will output the same value

```
printf( "&*c = %p\n", ( void * )&*c );

printf( "&c[0] = %p\n", ( void * )&c[0] );
```